# Second monitor disappears from "extend" view

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors

I have Windows 10 on a laptop, with an external monitor. Today, when I worked with both monitors in "Extend" mode, the external monitor disappeared; when I opened "Display Settings" and clicked "Detect", Windows could not detect it.

[image]

I restarted the computer, and then I saw the second monitor again for several seconds, but then it disappeared again. I replaced the connecting cable (a VGA cable), but it did not solve the problem. How can I get the second monitor back?

Comment: Quick tests; try another cable, try another monitor.

Comment: 1.Update the latest graphics card drivers from the manufacturer’s website. 2.Check the refresh rates of each montior 
3.Switch to another project mode: PC screen only/Duplicate/Extend/Second screen only.